# 2SXC not working on clean DNN 9.3.2 install

Tags: 2sxc, dotnetnuke, dnn9

Tried to work with 2SXC on a clean DNN 9.3.2 install and tried with version 10.1. as well as 9.43.01 LTS version. No Luck. Never had this before. Any known problem with this version of DNN?

As soon as I click the "Manage Apps" option I get an error modal:

Had an error talking to the server (status 400).
Message: Bad Request
Detail: Die Sequenz enthält kein übereinstimmendes Element.

if you are an advanced user you can learn more about what went wrong - discover how on 2sxc.org/help?tag=debug

Below see the DNN error log. Any idea what could be causing the problem?

AbsoluteURL:/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/eav/system/features
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:e6fd83b0-31f7-4ece-b661-957e65d75853
AssemblyVersion:
PortalId:-1
UserId:-1
TabId:-1
RawUrl:
Referrer:
UserAgent:
ExceptionHash:lOI7WOo+O7a6JaDm7qb88K6T7+E=
Message:Die Sequenz enthält kein übereinstimmendes Element.
StackTrace:
bei System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) bei ToSic.Eav.DataSources.Caches.BaseCache.GetZoneAppInternal(Nullable`1 zoneId, Nullable`1 appId) in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.DataSources\Caches\BaseCache.cs:Zeile 192. bei ToSic.Eav.Apps.SystemRuntime.ZoneIdOfApp(Int32 appId) bei ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.EavApiProxies.SystemController.Features(Int32 appId) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\Sxc WebApi\EavApiProxies\SystemController.cs:Zeile 24. bei lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters) bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__18`1.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__18`1.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
InnerMessage:
InnerStackTrace:
Source:System.Core
FileName:
FileLineNumber:0
FileColumnNumber:0
Method:
Server-Name s18611576

Comment: Sounds like something didn't complete during the installation....I just ran a setup on dnn 9.3.2 for my DNN-Connect demo and everything worked. So it must be something unique on your setup.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Tried reinstalling the module, but same error. I think we will now set up the DNN install from scratch and try again.

Comment: Can#t get it to work. Reinstalled DNN 9.3.2 then first tried 2SXC 09.43.01. Then it showed the "Upgrade didn't complete" notification although it was no upgrade. Then clicked the "complete upgrade" button and waited approx. 20 Minutes. After it completed same issue. I realized that the error modal shows only when using the APP module (as soon as I click "manage apps") and not when using the CONTENT module. Screenshot: https://neckheyn.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2SXC-App-Error.png

Comment: This doesn't sound like a new dnn 9.3.2, but more like a re-install of 2sxc. In such cases, certain files are still left behind (because we cannot fully control the un-install of 2sxc in DNN). To corner the problem, please first check with a completely new DNN 9.3.2 to see if it still happens (I suggest you use nvQuickSite to get a new dnn up in 2 minutes). I just tried this again and didn't run into problems. Once we've confirmed that, we can try to figure out what's wrong with your existing install.

Comment: It was a new installation. The error occurs from this url:
`/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/eav/system/features?appId=0`

This is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdZ7Y.jpg

Comment: So the screenshot you're showing is because you tried to call the URL directly, and it's missing security headers. What dialog were you opening, that caused this error? thx and sorry for the problems :(

Comment: I think it was the "Manage Apps" after placing the Apps Module.

Comment: It shows when I click manage Apps, so this is where I go to create a new App. We actually retried it on a completely new server but we get the same errors on DNN 9.3

Comment: Sorry, don't really have a guess for now :(. Note that I recommend to run all servers in English, so the error messages you get better match stuff on google.

Comment: Just as a side-note: the endpoint you are accessing only provides very little data to the UI, to enable/disable some features. So it's not exactly rocket science; I don't even think it needs the DB.

Comment: BTW: I just noticed that the thing is complaining about running portalid -1. that of course looks pretty wrong. I don't have a solution, but I'm wondering why -1, as that's never a real portal id. 
Do you still get the error once you've installed an existing app (so does it only happen when the installation is completely virgin?)

Comment: I think we were just able to reproduce the issue! I'll keep you posted...

Comment: I just created a pre-release of 9.43.02 - should fix this :)

Comment: Nice! We'll try. Are you going to post an install package as well?

Comment: By the way, why are you fixing it in the 9.x version instead of 10.x ??

Comment: yes, the rewest 9.43.02 fixes it - install package now included (I had forgotten to upload that) https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/releases/tag/v09.43.02b

Comment: It works. Thank you. Are going to apply the same fixes to the 10.x version?

Comment: yes, next release probably next week.